# How to plot points on a grid given by two vectors?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to do a very simple task that is automatic on Matlab for example, but it is not trivial for me in Mathematica:

Given two vectors for example:

```
x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
y = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20}
```

I want to plot on the X-Y plane the points that fit the corresponding couples:

```
 {x[[1]],y[[1]]};....;{x[[10]],y[[10]]}
```

I want to do it directly only by using x and y as vectors and not run on the components separately, I tried to use ListPlot:

```
ListPlot[x,y]
```

but it didn't plot anything and just printed:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16,  18, 20}]
```

Comment: try `ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]`

Comment: `ListPlot[Transpose[{x, y}]]`

Comment: Amazing thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all comments, The right code should be:

```
  ListPlot[Transpose[{x,y}]]
```